# Can I include image URL options with Synthesis field rendering helpers?

Tags: media-library, urls, synthesis

I'm on Sitecore 8.2 with Synthesis 8.2.6.
I'm currently using the provided helpers `Field.RenderedValue` and `Field.Url`.

I'd like to request the images with specific size parameters depending on the control being rendered.
Do I need to create my own render of this, or is there a way to impact what args are used for the media Url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Synthesis has an extension method for `ImageField`s called `RenderDpiAware` [(link)](https://github.com/blipson89/Synthesis/blob/8.2.6/Source/Synthesis.Mvc/Extensions/ImageFields.cs#L56-L98) that allows you to specify a bunch of sizes to be used in a CSS source set.

Additionally, the `Render()` extension method [(link)](https://github.com/blipson89/Synthesis/blob/8.2.6/Source/Synthesis.Mvc/Extensions/ImageFields.cs#L28-L40) on `ImageField`s has the ability to set a max width and max height. In a razor view, it would look like:

`@Model.YourImageField.Render(maxWidth: 100, maxHeight: 100)` (both fields are optional, so you don't *need* to specify both).

Comment: I hadn't yet included the Synthesis.Mvc NuGet package, which I needed so I could have the .Render() helper.

Comment: Note: because were using maxHeight and maxWidth, scaling an image up will not happen